# Is the partial order of equational theories of a single binary operation dense?

Tags: universal-algebra

Let our signature be a single binary operation $\{*\}$. Consider the set of equational theories of that signature, partially ordered by inclusion. Is that partial order dense?

Comment: I suspect you want your theories to be *deductively closed*, right (e.g. no distinction between $\{x*x=x\}$ and $\{y*y=y\}$)? So you're equivalently asking about the *(opposite of the)* partial order of varieties of magmas under inclusion.

Comment: The set of equational theories in a fixed language under the inclusion order forms an algebraic lattice. Any algebraic lattice of more than one element will have elements $a<b$ with no element strictly between $a$ and $b$. (Choose $b$ compact and $a$ a lower cover of $b$.)

Comment: @KeithKearnes I think that should be an answer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah, by equational theory I mean deductively closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set of equational theories in a fixed language under the inclusion order forms an algebraic lattice. Any algebraic lattice of more than one element will have elements $<$ with no element strictly between $$ and $$. (Choose $$ compact and $$ a lower cover of $$.)