# Is the set of identities of a single binary operation densely ordered under this strict partial order?

Tags: universal-algebra

This is somewhat similar to my previous question, here: [Is the partial order of equational theories of a single binary operation dense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4474994/is-the-partial-order-of-equational-theories-of-a-single-binary-operation-dense), but slightly different. Consider the set $S$ of identities of a single binary operation $\{*\}$. So, for example, the commutative identity $(x*y)=(y*x)$ is in $S$. I define a relation $<$ on $S$ by saying that, given identities $E$ and $E'$ in $S$, $E < E'$ holds iff $E$ can be derived from $E'$, but not vice versa. It is easy to prove that $<$ is a strict partial order. My question is, is the order dense? That is, if $E < E'$, does there exist a $E''$ in $S$ such that $E<E''<E'$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is No, the order is not dense.

Let $E'$ be the identity $x=y$ and let $E$ be the identity
$$
(x*((y*x)*x))*(y*(z*x))=y.
$$
Then $E<E'$ and there is no strictly intermediate identity $E''$. The reason for this is that $E'$ axiomatizes the trivial variety in this language (as is easily seen) while $E$ axiomatizes a minimal variety in this language (which is not easily seen).

For the not-easily-seen part, I am using one of the results of the paper

*Short Single Axioms for Boolean Algebra* 
William McCune, Robert Veroff, Branden Fitelson, Kenneth Harris, Andrew Feist, Larry Wos 
Journal of Automated Reasoning volume 29, pages 1-16 (2002)

They prove that $E$ is the shortest single axiom for the Sheffer stroke (NAND or NOR) operation.